# Generate Points on Circle with Radius (r = 1)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, bivariate-distributions

How do I plot points in the region of a circle with radius 1, given a uniform bivariate distribution (X,Y)?

Conditional PDF of y given x is provided as: (1) / (2 * sqrt(1 - x^2))

Any help is greatly appreciated.
(I am coding in Maple).

Thanks!

Comment: Continuing to outsource your HW? Did you explain this approach to your TA?

Answer (score 2):

> I'm addressing the $\textit{first question}$:
>   'How do I plot points in this region ?'.

Generate a pair of 'random numbers' $\xi_{r}$ and $\xi_{t}$ which are uniformly distributed in $\left[0,1\right)$. A point$\left(x,y\right)$ in the unit disk is given by:
$$
x = \sqrt{\xi_{r}}\cos\left(2\pi\xi_{t}\right)\,,\qquad y = \sqrt{\xi_{r}}\sin\left(2\pi\xi_{t}\right)
$$

---

The following $\texttt{Mathematica}$ code makes the job with $10000$ points:

```
Clear[n,r,randDisk1,t];

randDisk1[] :=
Module[{r, t},
r = Sqrt[RandomReal[]];
t = 2 Pi RandomReal[];
{r Cos[t], r Sin[t]}
]

ListPlot[Table[randDisk1[], {n, 1, 10000}], 
PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.002]}, Axes -> False,AspectRatio -> 1]
```

---

[image]

Comment: Proof? You know, like, on a *maths* site...